# How to add text to QR plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, qr-code, barcode

I am unable to add text to my QR code plot. I would like an annotation at the bottom of the QR code that reads the text string (in this case, "hello"). When I run the script below, I just get the QR code without any annotation. What is the best way to add text?

```
# Libraries
library(qrcode)
library(ggplot2)

# QR String
string <- "test"

# Create QR Code
qrcode_label <- qrcode_gen(string, plotQRcode = TRUE)

# Annotate QR Code
#qrcode_label_annotated <- qrcode_label + text("hello")

# Save QR Code as PNG
ggsave("qrcode.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have done it. Using magick.

```html
library(magick)
  library(rsvg)
  for (i in a) {
    print(i)
    ii=image_read(i)
    ii=image_annotate(ii,paste(tools::file_path_sans_ext(i)),  gravity= "south",size=20)
    print(ii)
    ##image_write(ii, path = "C:\\temp\\"&ii*".png", format = "png")
    image_write(ii, format <- "png", path = paste0(i, ""))
```